# WebAssembly cant compile simple classes?

Tags: webassembly

I have been playing around with the WebAssembly Explorer just to get used to the general concept and I believe im getting wrong output:

C++ code:

```
class Rectangle {
  void draw(int fooBar) {};
};
```

The output to webassembly:

```
(module
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
)
```

Honestly this doesnt look right. Why doesnt it show the function? I actually expected the explorer to export a func which might look something like this:

```
  (export "_Z4drawi" (func $_Z4drawi))
  (func $_Z4drawi (param $0 i32)
```

Instead however it pretends as if the object was empty...why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM is eliminating your function because it's unused.

Try using it and making it no-inline (to prevent it from just getting eliminated as well):

```
class Rectangle {
  public:
  Rectangle() {}
  __attribute__((noinline)) void draw(int fooBar) {}
};

int main() {
  Rectangle r;
  r.draw(42);
}
```

And you get:

```
(module
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (export "main" (func $main))
  (func $main (result i32)
    (local $0 i32)
    (i32.store offset=4
      (i32.const 0)
      (tee_local $0
        (i32.sub
          (i32.load offset=4
            (i32.const 0)
          )
          (i32.const 16)
        )
      )
    )
    (call $_ZN9Rectangle4drawEi
      (i32.add
        (get_local $0)
        (i32.const 8)
      )
      (i32.const 42)
    )
    (i32.store offset=4
      (i32.const 0)
      (i32.add
        (get_local $0)
        (i32.const 16)
      )
    )
    (i32.const 0)
  )
  (func $_ZN9Rectangle4drawEi (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32)
  )
)
```

Using no-inline is a hack around trivial code getting optimized out. You could also mark it as used:

```
class Rectangle {
  public:
  Rectangle() {}
  __attribute__((used)) void draw(int fooBar) {}
};
```

Then you'd get:

```
(module
  (table 0 anyfunc)
  (memory $0 1)
  (export "memory" (memory $0))
  (func $_ZN9Rectangle4drawEi (param $0 i32) (param $1 i32)
  )
)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Its really informative and its clear now that the compiler does some optimization.

Comment: By the way, the assembly code generated will be the same for all languages I assume? Im glad they finally finished the spec for the text based version

Comment: What I dont understand though: what makes the code trivial? Maybe I want the code to execute

Comment: The assembly is the same *language* for any language that targets WebAssembly, but C++ versus Rust may use different constructs. That all depends on the compiler being used by the developer. The same applies to optimization settings: try compiling at O0 versus O3 and notice code differences.

Comment: On trivial code: that's LLVM at work. They see the function is unused and just remove it, or it gets inline and is then unused causing its removal. That's not special to WebAssembly, it's how C++ compilers work in general: if they can prove something is unused then they're free to get rid of it.